React Font Awesome 6 Non-self-hosted Kit solution
So my company has a FontAwesome pro license and currently uses the FontAwesoneIcon react package. It delivers the icons as svgs. But my company uses custom icons so we want to migrate to use the Font Awesome Kit solution. Currently, we DO NOT download the kit (self hosted) we access the icons online through the SDK. We previously used the FontAwesomeIcon react package and have not completed the migration. We are in the process of building a POC. We have discovered the Kit does not have a package for React and the existing FontAwesoneIcon package does not handle custom icons or Kits therefore we have gone ahead and added the Kit SDK call to the HTML of our pages and created a custom React component that takes the same props that the previous package component took so we can change out the old package components with the new custom ones. This new solution simply creates a "i" tag and adds the icons via className leveraging the icon.name prop, among other props. It works fine in POC.
I would however like to build my own svg in the component rather than use an "i" tag and classes but that would require extracting the SVG path data from the SDK. I do not know how to do this.
The reason I want to use svgs and the classes that are applied to FA svgs (fa-inline-svg, etc) is due to the effort to change all of our apps to switch to using this new component. Not only do we need to change all the component names and paths from the old FontAwesoneIcon ones but we will have to deal with style changes where the existing styles depend on the SVG elements and classes.
I hope this makes sense. So the main question is this: How can I query the Font Awesome Kit SDK to return the SVG values I need, using the icon prefix and icon name?
@dana woodman
